# How to write a test for validates_uniqueness_of with scope and presence: true RSpec Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, scope, rspec-rails

Trying to write a test to verify uniqueness of :user_id with scope :board_id.

Model:

```rb
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :board
  belongs_to :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :board_id, presence: true
end
```

I try to test it like:

```rb
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:user_id) } 
it expect.to have_many(:membership).through(:board_id)
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using shoulda-matchers it can be done in two expectations (even though it's a single model line):

```
it { should validate_presence_of(:user_id) }
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:user_id).scoped_to(:board_id) }
```

Comment: Thanks [Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5025116/sebastian-palma) for clarification, it works)